# can i store data in android sqlite when phonescreen is locked using service?

Tags: android, sqlite, sockets, headset

i am developing an application where i need to store data in sqlite when the screen is locked
simply i will detect an input hardware in the headset socket .. read some data from it and store it in the sqlite
also can i launch a specific service in an application when the device is detected ? 
i have searched and found that i cannot eep the service running for a long time in the background but also i cannot find any other workarounds 
could it be done using services ? 
also what will be the drawbacks on the performance ?
and for how long i can keep the service running in the background